# AS3: Why is this flash navigation behaving weirdly?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm newish to AS3 and I'm trying to build an image navigation for my site.

Basically the 4 categories are represented by images (or colored rectangles for the time being). There are 4 invisible mcs over each area. The recs start off blurry and small, and on mouse over the invis mc, the corresponding rec will enlarge, then on mouse out the rec will shrink back to the starting position.

Everything seems to be working fine when the mouse goes over everything slowly, but when you move the mouse fast, the images enlarge and freezes randomly - basically behaving unexpectedly.

[Here is the fla](http://www.muudles.com/downloads/demo.fla), and [here is the swf](http://www.muudles.com/downloads/demo.swf).

I know I might have written the code ridiculously long, but its the only way I know how atm. So please don't shorten it too much because I wouldn't know how to update it in the future, or if you do, it will be great if you could please give me a clear explanation on what is going on.

The code:

```
import flash.net.navigateToURL;    
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.filters.*;
import caurina.transitions.Tweener;
import caurina.transitions.properties.FilterShortcuts;
FilterShortcuts.init();  // Initialize shortcuts for tween


/**** the 4 boxes' starting position ****/

var box1X:int = 135;    
var box1Y:int = 205;
var box1W:int = 96;     
var box1H:int = 85;
Tweener.addTween (box1_mc,  {_Blur_blurX:10, _Blur_blurY:10, _Blur_quality:2, width:box1W, height:box1H, x:box1X, y:box1Y});
var box1LabelX:int = 137;   
var box1LabelY:int = 123;
var box1LabelW:int = 124.5;     
var box1LabelH:int = 21;
Tweener.addTween (box1_label, {_Blur_blurX:1.2, _Blur_blurY:1.2, _Blur_quality:2, width:box1LabelW, height:box1LabelH, x:box1LabelX, y:box1LabelY});

var box2X:int = 384;    
var box2Y:int = 196;
var box2W:int = 158;    
var box2H:int = 152;
Tweener.addTween (box2_mc,  {_Blur_blurX:10, _Blur_blurY:10, _Blur_quality:2, width:box2W, height:box2H, x:box2X, y:box2Y});
var box2LabelX:int = 382;   
var box2LabelY:int = 88;
var box2LabelW:int = 124.5;     
var box2LabelH:int = 21;
Tweener.addTween (box2_label, {_Blur_blurX:1.2, _Blur_blurY:1.2, _Blur_quality:2, width:box2LabelW, height:box2LabelH, x:box2LabelX, y:box2LabelY});

var box3X:int = 640;    
var box3Y:int = 206;
var box3W:int = 90;     
var box3H:int = 89;
Tweener.addTween (box3_mc,  {_Blur_blurX:10, _Blur_blurY:10, _Blur_quality:2, width:box3W, height:box3H, x:box3X, y:box3Y});
var box3LabelX:int = 639;   
var box3LabelY:int = 136;
var box3LabelW:int = 124.5;     
var box3LabelH:int = 21;
Tweener.addTween (box3_label, {_Blur_blurX:1.2, _Blur_blurY:1.2, _Blur_quality:2, width:box3LabelW, height:box3LabelH, x:box3LabelX, y:box3LabelY});


var box4X:int = 851;    
var box4Y:int = 203;
var box4W:int = 42;     
var box4H:int = 105;
Tweener.addTween (box4_mc,  {_Blur_blurX:10, _Blur_blurY:10, _Blur_quality:2, width:box4W, height:box4H, x:box4X, y:box4Y});
var box4LabelX:int = 854;   
var box4LabelY:int = 123;
var box4LabelW:int = 124.5;     
var box4LabelH:int = 21;
Tweener.addTween (box4_label, {_Blur_blurX:1.2, _Blur_blurY:1.2, _Blur_quality:2, width:box4LabelW, height:box4LabelH, x:box4LabelX, y:box4LabelY});




/**** Starting to tween ****/

invis1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, box1Handler);
invis1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, box1Handler);
invis1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, box1Handler);
function box1Handler(e=null){
    if(e.type == "mouseOver"){
        Tweener.addTween (box1_mc,  {time:0.5, _Blur_blurX:0, _Blur_blurY:0, scaleX:0.95, scaleY:0.95, x:box1X+10, y:box1Y+30, transition:"linear"});
        Tweener.addTween (box1_label, {time:0.2, alpha:0, transition:"linear"});
        Tweener.addTween (box1_label, {time:0.2, delay:0.2, alpha:0, scaleX:1, scaleY:1,   x:box1LabelX+10, y:box1LabelY-40, transition:"linear"});
        Tweener.addTween (box1_label, {time:0.5, delay:0.6, alpha:1, scaleX:1.5, scaleY:1.5, x:box1LabelX+10, y:box1LabelY-40, _Blur_blurX:0, _Blur_blurY:0, transition:"easeOutElastic"});
        trace(0.5);
    } else if(e.type == "mouseOut"){
        Tweener.addTween (box1_mc,  {time:0.4, _Blur_blurX:10, _Blur_blurY:10, _Blur_quality:2, width:box1W, height:box1H, x:box1X, y:box1Y, transition:"linear"});
        Tweener.addTween (box1_label, {time:0.2, alpha:0, transition:"linear"});
        Tweener.addTween (box1_label, {time:0.2, delay:0.2, _Blur_blurX:1.2, _Blur_blurY:1.2, _Blur_quality:2, width:box1LabelW, height:box1LabelH, x:box1LabelX, y:box1LabelY, alpha:0});
        Tweener.addTween (box1_label, {time:0.2, delay:0.4, _Blur_blurX:1.2, _Blur_blurY:1.2, _Blur_quality:2, width:box1LabelW, height:box1LabelH, x:box1LabelX, y:box1LabelY, alpha:1,transition:"linear"});
        trace("box1 shrink");
    } else if(e.type == "click"){
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest("index.html"), '_self');
    } else if(mouseX<0 || mouseX>960) {
        trace("gone");
    }
}


invis2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, box2Handler);
invis2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, box2Handler);
invis2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, box2Handler);
function box2Handler(e=null){
    if(e.type == "mouseOver"){
        Tweener.addTween (box2_mc,  {time:0.5, _Blur_blurX:0, _Blur_blurY:0, scaleX:0.95, scaleY:0.95, x:box2X+0, y:box2Y+30, transition:"linear"});
        Tweener.addTween (box2_label, {time:0.2, alpha:0, transition:"linear"});
        Tweener.addTween (box2_label, {time:0.2, delay:0.2, alpha:0, scaleX:1, scaleY:1,   x:box2LabelX, y:box2LabelY-10, transition:"linear"});
        Tweener.addTween (box2_label, {time:0.5, delay:0.6, alpha:1, scaleX:1.5, scaleY:1.5, x:box2LabelX, y:box2LabelY-10, _Blur_blurX:0, _Blur_blurY:0, transition:"easeOutElastic"});
        trace("box2 enlarge");
    } else if(e.type == "mouseOut"){
        Tweener.addTween (box2_mc,  {time:0.4, _Blur_blurX:10, _Blur_blurY:10, _Blur_quality:2, width:box2W, height:box2H, x:box2X, y:box2Y, transition:"linear"});
        Tweener.addTween (box2_label, {time:0.2, alpha:0, transition:"linear"});
        Tweener.addTween (box2_label, {time:0.2, delay:0.2, _Blur_blurX:1.2, _Blur_blurY:1.2, _Blur_quality:2, width:box2LabelW, height:box2LabelH, x:box2LabelX, y:box2LabelY, alpha:0});
        Tweener.addTween (box2_label, {time:0.2, delay:0.4, _Blur_blurX:1.2, _Blur_blurY:1.2, _Blur_quality:2, width:box2LabelW, height:box2LabelH, x:box2LabelX, y:box2LabelY, alpha:1,transition:"linear"});
        trace("box2 shrink");
    } else if(e.type == "click"){
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest("box2.html"), '_self');
    }
}


invis3_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, box3Handler);
invis3_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, box3Handler);
invis3_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, box3Handler);
function box3Handler(e=null){
    if(e.type == "mouseOver"){
        Tweener.addTween (box3_mc,  {time:0.5, _Blur_blurX:0, _Blur_blurY:0, scaleX:0.95, scaleY:0.95, x:box3X, y:box3Y+30, transition:"linear"});
        Tweener.addTween (box3_label, {time:0.2, alpha:0, transition:"linear"});
        Tweener.addTween (box3_label, {time:0.2, delay:0.2, alpha:0, scaleX:1, scaleY:1,   x:box3LabelX, y:box3LabelY-50, transition:"linear"});
        Tweener.addTween (box3_label, {time:0.5, delay:0.6, alpha:1, scaleX:1.5, scaleY:1.5, x:box3LabelX, y:box3LabelY-50, _Blur_blurX:0, _Blur_blurY:0, transition:"easeOutElastic"});
        trace("box3 enlarge");
    } else if(e.type == "mouseOut"){
        Tweener.addTween (box3_mc,  {time:0.4, _Blur_blurX:10, _Blur_blurY:10, _Blur_quality:2, width:box3W, height:box3H, x:box3X, y:box3Y, transition:"linear"});
        Tweener.addTween (box3_label, {time:0.2, alpha:0, transition:"linear"});
        Tweener.addTween (box3_label, {time:0.2, delay:0.2, _Blur_blurX:1.2, _Blur_blurY:1.2, _Blur_quality:2, width:box3LabelW, height:box3LabelH, x:box3LabelX, y:box3LabelY, alpha:0});
        Tweener.addTween (box3_label, {time:0.2, delay:0.4, _Blur_blurX:1.2, _Blur_blurY:1.2, _Blur_quality:2, width:box3LabelW, height:box3LabelH, x:box3LabelX, y:box3LabelY, alpha:1,transition:"linear"});
        trace("box3 shrink");
    } else if(e.type == "click"){
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest("box3s.html"), '_self');
    }
}

invis4_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, box4Handler);
invis4_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, box4Handler);
invis4_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, box4Handler);
function box4Handler(e=null){
    if(e.type == "mouseOver"){
        Tweener.addTween (box4_mc,  {time:0.5, _Blur_blurX:0, _Blur_blurY:0, scaleX:1, scaleY:1, y:box4Y+30, transition:"linear"});
        Tweener.addTween (box4_label, {time:0.2, alpha:0, transition:"linear"});
        Tweener.addTween (box4_label, {time:0.2, delay:0.2, alpha:0, scaleX:1, scaleY:1,   y:box4LabelY-50, transition:"linear"});
        Tweener.addTween (box4_label, {time:0.5, delay:0.6, alpha:1, scaleX:1.5, scaleY:1.5, y:box4LabelY-50, _Blur_blurX:0, _Blur_blurY:0, transition:"easeOutElastic"});
        trace("box4 enlarge");
    } else if(e.type == "mouseOut"){
        Tweener.addTween (box4_mc,  {time:0.4, _Blur_blurX:10, _Blur_blurY:10, _Blur_quality:2, width:box4W, height:box4H, x:box4X, y:box4Y, transition:"linear"});
        Tweener.addTween (box4_label, {time:0.2, alpha:0, transition:"linear"});
        Tweener.addTween (box4_label, {time:0.2, delay:0.2, _Blur_blurX:1.2, _Blur_blurY:1.2, _Blur_quality:2, width:box4LabelW, height:box4LabelH, x:box4LabelX, y:box4LabelY, alpha:0});
        Tweener.addTween (box4_label, {time:0.2, delay:0.4, _Blur_blurX:1.2, _Blur_blurY:1.2, _Blur_quality:2, width:box4LabelW, height:box4LabelH, x:box4LabelX, y:box4LabelY, alpha:1,transition:"linear"});
        trace("box4 shrink");
    } else if(e.type == "click"){
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest("box4.html"), '_self');
    }
}
```

Update: Added removeTween for box1, still not functioning properly:

```
invis1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, box1Handler);
invis1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, box1Handler);
invis1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, box1Handler);
function box1Handler(e=null){
    if(e.type == "mouseOver"){
        Tweener.addTween (box1_mc,  {time:0.5, _Blur_blurX:0, _Blur_blurY:0, scaleX:0.95, scaleY:0.95, x:box1X+10, y:box1Y+30, transition:"linear"});
        Tweener.addTween (box1_label, {time:0.2, alpha:0, transition:"linear"});
        Tweener.addTween (box1_label, {time:0.2, delay:0.2, alpha:0, scaleX:1, scaleY:1,   x:box1LabelX+10, y:box1LabelY-40, transition:"linear"});
        Tweener.addTween (box1_label, {time:0.5, delay:0.6, alpha:1, scaleX:1.5, scaleY:1.5, x:box1LabelX+10, y:box1LabelY-40, _Blur_blurX:0, _Blur_blurY:0, transition:"easeOutElastic"});
        trace(0.5);
    } else if(e.type == "mouseOut"){
        //** Added here:
        Tweener.addTween (box1_mc,  {time:0.4, _Blur_blurX:10, _Blur_blurY:10, _Blur_quality:2, width:box1W, height:box1H, x:box1X, y:box1Y, transition:"linear", onComplete:removeTween}); 
        Tweener.addTween (box1_label, {time:0.2, alpha:0, transition:"linear"});
        Tweener.addTween (box1_label, {time:0.2, delay:0.2, _Blur_blurX:1.2, _Blur_blurY:1.2, _Blur_quality:2, width:box1LabelW, height:box1LabelH, x:box1LabelX, y:box1LabelY, alpha:0});
        //** Added here:
        Tweener.addTween (box1_label, {time:0.2, delay:0.4, _Blur_blurX:1.2, _Blur_blurY:1.2, _Blur_quality:2, width:box1LabelW, height:box1LabelH, x:box1LabelX, y:box1LabelY, alpha:1,transition:"linear", onComplete:removeTween}); 
        trace("box1 shrink");
    } else if(e.type == "click"){
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest("index.html"), '_self');
    } else if(mouseX<0 || mouseX>960) {
        trace("gone");
    }
}

function removeTween():void {
    Tweener.removeTweens(box1_mc, "x", "y", "alpha", "_Blur_blurX", "_Blur_blurY", "width", "height");
    Tweener.removeTweens(box1_label, "x", "y", "alpha", "_Blur_blurX", "_Blur_blurY", "width", "height");
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code directly here, please? At least a small chunk of it, if it really is that long.

Comment: I'm not seeing where you're actually _calling_ removeTween().  Try adding a call to it in box1Handler. Also, you might want to consider breaking your code up diffferently. If you have a mouseOver, mouseOut, click handler, each of which you use for all boxes, then you can use e.currentTarget (assuming you put in the data type for e eventually) and not need so much repeated code.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're not canceling tweens. items seem to be tweened both smaller and larger at the same time.

since it looks like you are using Tweener, try using [`removeTweens()`](http://hosted.zeh.com.br/tweener/docs/en-us/methods/Tweener_removeTweens.html) before applying new tweens to your assets.

Comment: Hi gthmb, I've added removeTweens (see updated codes in the question), but its not doing anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I know when I used TweenMax in the past, which presumably is very similar to Tweener, the way I recall solving this type of issue was to create an actual instance of TweenMax instead of calling it statically every time. I'm not familiar with tweener, but if it is like TweenMax, instead of doing something like this (*UNTESTED CODE, more like pseudo code really*):

```
Tweener.addTween(...);
Tweener.addTween(...);
Tweener.addTween(...);
```

I would suggest something like:

```
    var myTweener:Tweener = new Tweener(); //Decalare this where it will be accessable to multiple functions.
    myTweener.addTween(...);
...
```

Then, whenever you want to interupt the current tween you would simply reference the same object with a new "tween" method call `myTweener.addTween(...);`. With TweenMax the new tween would pick up from where the already in progress tween left off, assuming it is from the same tween object instance and not from a static call.

If you want to read more about TweenMax go here: http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/

It's been my preferred method of tweening in Flash, but I haven't tweened in over a year so if I said something wrong forgive me:) Hope that helps!